# Meaning of "纏わり" in this sentence?

Tags: translation

Two characters are insulting each other there, one of them said this.

> どうせ陰湿に纏わりついてるだけでしょうよ

The "陰湿に纏わり" is tough for me to understand. I know "陰湿" means shady/underhanded. But I don't what the function of 纏わり here

Comment: Could it be `纏わりつく`? https://jisho.org/search/纏わりつく

Comment: Yes. Thanks. My question was what 纏わり meant when used with 陰湿

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are getting the nuance.「陰湿{いんしつ}」here in 「陰湿{いんしつ}に纏{まと}わりついてる」means "*nasty / sneaky / underhanded / shady*".

「纏{まと}わり付{つ}く」is normally used as "something is always staying by your side and never wont' leave" or "Something is coiling around the body and it does not allow to let go".

So, all in all,

> どうせ陰湿{いんしつ}に纏{まと}わりついてるだけでしょうよ

means that he/she is saying to the opponent;

*"Anyhow, you are just nastily and sneakingly coiling around me aren't you?"*

Answer (score 2):

> どうせ陰湿に纏わりついてるだけでしょうよ

纏わりつく is a compound verb/複合動詞 (made of まつわる/まとわる+つく), meaning "cling to" "follow around", etc.

陰湿に is the continuative/adverbial form of the na-adjective 陰湿**な**, which means "malicious, insidious, underhanded," etc.
So 陰湿**に** means "insidious*ly*", "underhanded*ly*" etc. and here it modifies/describes the the verb まとわりつく adverbially.

So your sentence can translate to something along the lines of:

> You're just following [someone] around underhandedly after all, (right?)